# Change name of executable file when using chmod +x

Tags: python, chmod

I have python file `my_script.py`

When I run:

```
chmod +x my_script.py
```

I end up with two files that are called `my_script.py`, one executable file and one python file, when I try to get the size of the file:

```
du -sh my_script.py
```

I am getting the size of the python file (4.0K), but I want to know the size of the executable.

Is there a way to change a name of the executable file? To something say `my_script` without `.py` ?

Comment: They can't both be called the same - is one my_script.pyc by any chance?

Comment: Thanks everyone who tried to help, I think my misunderstanding of what happens when `chmod +x my_script.py` is ran is pretty severe, your answers have pointed that out :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only 1 file, `my_script.py`. Doing a simple `chmod +x` does NOT "end up with two files called `my_script.py`" (what would the 2nd `my_script.py` be called?).

Since Python is an interpreted language, you might want to consider the size of the `python` interpreter, and both the dynamic libraries and interpreted libraries it uses.

When the `execve` system call (see `man 2 execve`) notices that `my_script.py` is executable (has the `x` bit set), and begins with "`#!<interpreter>`" it runs `<interpreter> my_script.py` (`interpreter`> is probably `/usr/bin/python` in your case).

So, you can simply `mv my_script.py my_script`. Unlike that other operating system, Unix/Linux filenames do NOT govern how the files are executed.

Comment: `chmod +x` does not create a binary file, it just marks the file as executable (to be executed with python), so in order to run the executable I still need python installed on my system, is this right?

Comment: Yes, you need `python`, and both the dynamic libraries and interpreted (Python) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this command to change name of file while making it executable.

```
chmod +x my_script.py && mv my_script.py mv_myscript
```